# ASP.NET MVC 3 Query result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, html.hiddenfor

in my mvc 3 app with ef code first i have a database with 1 table

the column field is

ID

TIME1 Double
TIME2 Double
TIME3 Double

I need time3 is the result of the multiplication of time1 and time2 ... I did it with viewbag

```
Viewbag.Text = db.persons.Sum(o => o.Time1 * o.Time2);
```

But howunfortunately I can not associate the field Time3 the result ... here is my controller and view

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        person.Tempo3 = db.persons.Sum(o => o.Tempo1 * o.Tempo2);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.persons.Add(person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(person);
    }
```

}

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tempo1) @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tempo2) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Tempo3)
```

With HiddenFor the calculate don't work...how do this with linq query? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        newPerson = new db.persons {Tempo1 = person.Tempo1, Tempo2 = person.Tempo2};
        newPerson.Tempo3 = peson.Tempo1 * person.Tempo2; 

        db.persons.Add(newPerson);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(person);
}
```

Comment: Where i declare newPerson variable? In HttPost Method?

Comment: Thanks, it works. The value I have in my application, however, is in another table, if I write something like that I get error

Comment: This is my real code

var x = new Movement() { MovementID = movement.MovementID, EmployeID = movement.EmployeID, Time = movement.Time,};

Cost is in current table

x.Cost= movement.Time * movement.Employe.Money;

Money is in Employe Table

Comment: Just declare another variable and use Linq to get your money data from Employe table. Then use the new variable to do the math.

Comment: Like this?                 var x = new Movement() { MovementID = movement.MovementID, EmployeID = movement.EmployeID,Time = movement.Time};
var y = new Employe() { EmployeID = y.EmployeID, Money = y.Money };
                xCost = x.Time * y.Money;
                db.Movements.Add(z);

Comment: I get this error "Cannot use local variable y before it is declared

Comment: Lol damn my code is wrong...z is not declareed...this is my code sorry var x = new Movement() { MovementID = movement.MovementID, EmployeID = movement.EmployeID,Time = movement.Time}; var y = new Employe() { EmployeID = y.EmployeID, Money = y.Money }; x.Cost = x.Time * y.Money; db.Movement.Add(x)

Comment: Is it working now? I don't see an error there now that you have declared all ur variables lol

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/mvcpt/thread/5cdeb008-3f6e-4223-ac78-7bfdd03c5e99 see this. I resolve the problem.